# How do i extract key and value pair from an array of dictionaries?

Tags: ios, arrays, swift, dictionary

How do I extract key value pairs in an array of dictionaries to display the string  "Jane Doe (ID: 243) earns $58000.0 (including commission)" from the code below.

```
let empIDKey = "EmpID"
    let nameKey = "Name"
    // TODO:  Add extra keys here
    let payKey = "PayRate"
    
    // Create employees
    var emp1 = Dictionary<String, Any>()
    emp1[empIDKey] = 137
    emp1[nameKey] = "John Doe"
    // TODO: add pay value here
    emp1[payKey] = 35000.00
    
    var emp2 = Dictionary<String, Any>()
    emp2[empIDKey] = 243
    emp2[nameKey] = "Jane Doe"
    // TODO: add pay and bonus values here
    emp2[payKey] = 50000.00
    // Add employees to a list
    
    var employees = [Dictionary<String, Any>]()
    employees.append(emp1)
    employees.append(emp2)
    // TODO:  Display employee info
    
    for person in employees {
        // Grab each key, value pair from the person dictionary
        // and print it
        for (key,value) in person {
            print("\(key): \(value)")
        }
    }
```

Answer (score 1):

You have to get each value by its key

```
for person in employees {
    let id = person[empIDKey] as! Int
    let name = person[nameKey] as! String
    let pay = person[payKey] as! Double
    print("\(name) (ID: \(id) earns $\(pay) (including commission)")
}
```

Consider to use a custom struct to get rid of the type casts (and the keys).

Comment: The loop is performed twice, the values are printed for `emp1` and `emp2`.